# Bitnami MEANstack: express is not recognized

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, bitnami

I've recently installed a native installation of Bitnami MEANstack on Windows and tried to create my project using their tutorial [here](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/Bitnami_MEAN_Stack#How_to_start_with_a_sample_MEAN_project.3f).
However, on step 3, when I'm executing the command `express myproject` it gives an error: `'express' is not recognized as an internal or external command...`
Here are the solutions I already tried:

1. Running the provided console as Administrator
2. Reinstalled express using `npm install -g express -save`

Both of them didn't work. What solutions could I possibly do? Thanks in advance

Regards,
Daryll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install `express-generator` to get the `express` command:

```
npm install -g express-generator
```

Answer (score 5):

A Bitnami developer here.

This was an issue with the installer, which did not come with any NPM modules on Windows.
This was fixed in [version 3.0.7 of the Bitnami MEAN Stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/mean/installer), so downloading the installer again and installing it should work.